# Differences between environments in master pages

Tags: sharepoint-designer, master-page

I have an environment, on premises, when I create a new master page, it doesn't create a corresponding html file with it, even the OOB master pages, they don't have html file along with them, and I can edit the .master directly.

I have another office 365 site, where each master page has .html file with it, and you can't edit the .master, you need to edit the .html.

what's the catch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to enable Design Manager. By default it is activated on Publishing sites only. Please, follow instructions: http://www.idubbs.com/blog/2012/sharepoint-2013-enabling-design-manager/